# Debian packaging rules

Tags: deb

When I tried to make a link inside the rules file it didn't allow me.How can I make it?
Here is what I did.

```
#!/usr/bin/make -f
icon = $(CURDIR)/frontpage.png
script = $(CURDIR)/guilotinga.py
launcher = $(CURDIR)/internation.desktop

DEST1 = $(CURDIR)/debian/internation/usr/share/internation
DEST2 = $(CURDIR)/debian/internation/usr/share/applications

build: build-stamp

build-stamp:
    dh_testdir
    touch build-stamp

clean:
   dh_testdir
   dh_testroot
   rm -f build-stamp
   dh_clean

install: build clean $(icon) $(script) $(launcher) 
   dh_testdir
   dh_testroot
   dh_prep
   dh_installdirs

   mkdir -m 755 -p $(DEST1)
   mkdir -m 755 -p $(DEST2)
   install -m 666 $(icon) $(DEST1)
   install -m 777 $(script) $(DEST1)
   install -m 777 $(launcher) $(DEST2)
   ln -s usr/share/internation/guilotinga.py  /usr/bin/internation 
   (That's where I  stopped)
```

The line above is giving error saying I don't have enough privileges.What was my fault?

```
 binary-indep: build install
dh_testdir
dh_testroot
dh_installchangelogs
dh_installdocs
dh_installexamples
dh_installman
dh_link
dh_compress
dh_fixperms
dh_installdeb
dh_gencontrol
dh_md5sums
dh_builddeb

 binary-arch: build install

 binary: binary-indep binary-arch
   .PHONY: build clean binary-indep binary-arch binary install
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that what you wanted was to make a symlink *to* `/usr/bin/internation`, and have the link show up as `/usr/share/internation/guilotinga.py` when the package is installed. If so, you're just giving the link command backwards. You want

```
ln -s /usr/bin/internation usr/share/internation/guilotinga.py
```

As a further note, though, symlinks in Debian packages should not ever be absolute, unless you're symlinking one toplevel directory to another (see [Debian Policy](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-files.html#s10.5) section 10.5).

In your case, you probably don't need to change anything, since you have a call to `dh_link` in your build script. That tool will automatically fix noncompliant symlinks in the package build area (unless you're running in a super-ancient debhelper compat mode).

But if you want to avoid potentially confusing readers (or yourself), perhaps you ought to do

```
ln -s ../../bin/internation usr/share/internation/guilotinga.py
```